# Subsites limit in a flat hierarchy in a Site Collection in SharePoint 2010

Tags: capacity-planning

According to [SharePoint Server 2010 capacity management article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#SiteCollection) , We can have total 250,000   sites in a site collection.

I see some suggestions over the internet (like [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da/sharepoint2010general/thread/b6536af2-3177-41f3-9a0b-6d8960bdf20f))not to have more than 2000 subsites flat under a single site.

I want to know if we can create 250,000 directly under the root web or need to organize them in hierarchy such that no of subsites under a site < 2000. Do we have any recommendation from MS in this regard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Capacity Management" explicitly states that 2.000 is a threshold:

> Subsite | 2,000 per site view | Threshold
>   *The interface for enumerating subsites of a given Web site does not perform well as the number of subsites surpasses 2,000. Similarly, the
>   All Site Content page and the Tree View Control performance will
>   decrease significantly as the number of subsites grows.*

Note that a threshold is defined as:

> Configurable limits that can be exceeded to accommodate specific
>   requirements

This means that you can go over this limit if you have specific requirements AND that you thoroughly test your solution. With that said I do not think you should exceed it - rethink your design.

Comment: Ok, it means the limitation is just in the API\view which enumerates the subsites just like we have throttle limit of 5000 in a list. We don't have this limitation considering the capacity of site to hold the subsites.Am I correct?

Comment: I would not say *just* :-) Anywhere you iterate through sites will suffer. Note that this "threshold" also says that MSFT has not tested it beyond that limit, you have to do it yourself (and you can't complain later :-). But having a flat hierarchy like that seems like a bad idea imo.